# Jquery - apply css style to all elements within specifed div?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a situation where I am setting up a mobile theme for a wordpress website. 
Now what I would like to do is, grab any elements (p, divs, etcc) within the "#content" div, and apply css "width: 100%" to each of those child elements.

The reason I want to this is, in event somebody sets a fixed width for a div, I need it to overwrite that and revert it to 100% so it does not get cutoff when viewing on a mobile device with a smaller screen.

I would like to know how this can be achieved using Jquery.

I appreciate any help with this.
Thanks

Comment: If you're setting up a "mobile theme", surely you have a "mobile stylesheet"? Use CSS to make this change, not JavaScript..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Sometimes, jQuery is the *wrong way*...**

You shouldn't use jQuery unless it's offers a legitimate advantage. Often times using standard JavaScript will give you enormous performance advantages. With your situation, you could do something like the following:

```
var i,
    tags = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("*"),
    total = tags.length;
for ( i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
  tags[i].style.width = '100%';
}
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/otunam/3/edit

That being said, the jQuery method is pretty simple as well.

```
$('#content').find('*').width('100%');
```

This will run down into each level of `#content`, affecting all elements.

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/otunam/edit

**Performance Differences**

Using http://jsperf.com to compare the peformance difference here we can see the magnitude of speed raw JavaScript has over the jQuery alternative. In one test JavaScript was able to complete 300k operations in the time it took jQuery to complete 20k.

Test Now: http://jsperf.com/resizing-children

**But, Why JavaScript?**

Ultimately the question of whether jQuery or Raw JavaScript is better is a red-herring, distracting from the real question - why use scripting at all? If you detect a mobile browser, load a new stylesheet containing mobile rules:

```
#content * { width:100% }
```

Comment: Assuming I am already loading jquery for other purposes, will I still get a performance advantage by using standard js?

Comment: @levi You can see a performance comparison here: http://jsperf.com/resizing-children - it's much faster to go with raw JavaScript here.

Comment: Thanks for the terrific answer!

Comment: There should be at least one +1 for such a detailed answer. Done.

Comment: It is nice to know that there is no provided function in javascript to govern inheritances styles. So i wouldn't google for it. And i use Javascript always, not like majority of painters here.

Answer (score 10):

Here you go:

```
$('#content > *').css('width', '100%');
```

You could override it in CSS too:

```
#content > * {
    width: 100% !important
}
```

`!important` will assure that it overrides all (including inline style) definitions.

Answer (score 4):

`$("#content *").css("width","100%");` //everything inside #content

or

`$("#content > *").css("width","100%");` //just the direct children of #content

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
#content > * { /* applies to all direct children of #content */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Of if you have to use JavaScript/jQuery:

```
jQuery("#content > *").css("width", "100%");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
$("#container > *").css("color","red");
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.a { color: Navy; }
.b { color: Maroon; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="list1">
        <li ><a href="some.pdf">PDF</a></li>
        <li ><a href="some.pdf">d</a></li>
        <li ><a href="some.pdf">d</a></li>
        <li ><a href="some.pdf">d</a></li>
        <li ><a href="some.pdf">d</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="container">    
<p>This is paragraph 1</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2</p>
<p>This is paragraph 3</p>
<p>This is paragraph 4</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, fixing style sheets with JavaScript is a bad idea. You'll end up with a mess of automatically changed styles.

Luckily, you can solve your problem in CSS:

```
#content div,#content p,#content etcc {width: 100%;}
```

You can match all direct children by replacing the spaces with `>` (for example, `#content>div`).

If you don't want to enumerate all element names in `#content`, just use `#content *` (or `#content>*` for all direct children).